# $f(0) = 65$, $f(20) = 60$, Possible to determine $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus

My question is pretty much what the title says. I have the following info:
$f(0) = 65$ and $f(20) = 60$. The curve is also exponential, it says.

Is it really possible to determine $f(x)$ from this information alone and in that case, how is it done?

My literature only have very simple examples, and I can't find any lead in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Exponential (usually) means that $f(x) = ab^x$ (check your text for the exact definition). Solve the system of equations $f(0) = ab^0 = 65$ and $f(20) = ab^{20} = 60$.

Comment: Other definitions of the exponential function include $a  e^{cx}$. You can transform it into this form by letting $c = \log b$. Again, check your text.

Comment: Okey! I ended up with a=65 and b=0.996... I'm really not doing too well with logs yet, but I'll try to solve it using that method as well :) Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If the curve is exponential, it must be of the form:

$$f(x)=ae^{bx}$$

You have two values so you have two equations and two unknowns, so it's done.

Comment: You were all very helpful and I would gladly give you all "Correct answer", George V. Williams was first so he'll get it. But at least you'll have an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, for example, that $f(x)=ae^{-bx}$ by an exponential form?

In that case we get $f(0)=a$ and $f(20)=ae^{-20b}$

The first equation gives us $a$ and the second (take logs) gives $b$.

Note: Two equations, two unknowns. It doesn't always work, but it does show there is a chance.

Comment: Note - I chose the negative sign because the function was decreasing.

Comment: You were all very helpful and I would gladly give you all "Correct answer", George V. Williams was first so he'll get it. But at least you'll have an upvote :)